# How can I apply adding object in a collection to other linked collections automatically?

Tags: collections

[image]

As you can see in the picture above, adding objects in a collection do not applied to other linked collections contrary to editing existing objects.

If there's only one collection linked, it is easy problem solved by linking the added objects to linked collection.

But if there are many liked collections, linking new objects to those linked collections one by one would require a great deal of effort.

So I want adding some new objects to a collection applied to other linked collections automatically just like editing existing objects.

Is there any way that this is possible?

Comment: Hello :). It seems that *linked collections* only work between different *scenes*. Also,  when they're moved into the same scene, they get merged.

Comment: As I understand, creating a linked collection merely creates a new, independent collection with linked objects. But each collection can contain different objects afterwards. If you want the two collections to have exactly the same objects and update in real time, you should look into _collection instances_. But I think you won't be able to change the active camera, for instance. Otherwise, you could be able to do it with handlers and python scripting to detect when an object is added to a collection..?