# Help with linking collection data

Tags: collections

How do I link collections together so when you add an object in one collection, it appears in the other collections? If not, is there a way to do that?

Comment: Hello, so you want to have 2 independant collections, but be able to add an object in both collections at once ?

Comment: Yes. Two collections.

Comment: I think I found the answer here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/178168/how-can-i-apply-adding-object-in-a-collection-to-other-linked-collections-automa but is there a different way to do it without instances?

Comment: I don't know of an easy way... Have you ever scripted before in Blender with Python ? Is there a reason why you can't use collection instances ?

Comment: I'm not really familiar with scripting and the reason I can't use collection instances is that I need them to be on a different layer (I'm on blender version 2.92, by the way).

Comment: You can use collection instances on different view layers, what problems did you encounter with it ?

Comment: I'm having trouble finding out how to put collection instances on different view layers.

Comment: You can instance collections 2 ways : with Add > collection instance > *your collection* or by creating an empty, then go to the object properties, expand Instancing, and choose collection, and set the collection. Both should work regardless of your current view layer

Comment: I mean I need some instances on one layer and some on the other.

Comment: Oh okay, in that case it's very similar to this https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/220932/86891 (tldr : Put instanced collections in their own sub collection if you want to disable them)